# Does Nsight Visual Studio Edition support NVIDIA Quadro K5100M

Tags: visual-studio-2013, hardware, nvidia, nsight

It is not listed in "Nsight Visual Studio Edition Supported GPUs (Full List)", but I think it is strange if Nsight does not support this card. Does anybody know for sure whether it is supported or not?

Answer (score 0):

It does support that GPU. The website only listed that were fully tested with Nsight. In general, if GPUs with same ARCH are listed, it will work well no matter it's OEM name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming this. I was pretty confident that this was the case, but since it was not in the "official" list I couldn't be absolutely certain.